# trying to print all substrings of a specific srtring recursively without using loops at all

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking

i am trying to print all the sub strings of a string recursively without the help or without using loops at all. for example, if the string = "home"
it should print:

```
 h o m e ho hm he hom hoe hme om oe ome me home
```

if it was "bye" it should print:

```
 b y e by be ye bye
```

I only could do the following code:

```
public static void printSubs(String s){
    printSubs(s, "", 0, 0, s.length());
}

private static void printSubs(String s, String str, int i, int j, int length){
    if(i<length && j<length){
        if(j<s.length()){
            if(i==j)
                System.out.print(s.charAt(i)+" ");
            if(i<j){
                str+=s.charAt(i)+""+s.charAt(j);
                System.out.print(str+" ");
            }
            printSubs(s, "", i, j+1, length);
        }
        if(j==s.length()-1){
            printSubs(s.substring(i), "", i+1, i+1, length);
        }
    }
}
```

what is wrong with my code? it only prints :

```
h ho hm he o om oe e
```

thank you

Comment: You cannot modify strings, they are final.

Comment: why don't you use `s.toCharArray()` or `s.chars()` and mix all those chars as you wish?

Comment: Why 'without loops'?

Comment: @SteveSmith maybe it's a homework about recursion or something? there are better scenarios to practice this, but why not?

Comment: @SteveSmith it is an exercise, and we are not allowed to use any loops.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem in your code is that you don't use your buffer `str`at all, hence, all the string you will print will only be composed by 2 char: `str = s.charAt(i) + "" + s.charAt(j);` (the += is useless here because in your code `str == ""`every iteration). But I think the use of a buffer is the idea, you just need to figure out how to use it.
Another problem I think, is your last call `printSubs(s.substring(i), "", i+1, i+1, length);`that is very messy. 
• Either you substring "s" and you set `i = O` and `j = 0`to restart from the beginning with this substring without forgetting that `length = length -1` for it to end.

• Or you increment your indexes (i and j) and you keep your full string.